# Screenshot not Including CollectionView Header Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

So I am attempting to take a screenshot of my screen, then pass it onto the next view controller and set the screenshot as the background of that view controller. The screenshot I am trying to take is of a collection view with a header cell. The screenshot works perfectly except that it cuts out the header cell. Any advice on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I am using to create the screenshot.

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"menuSegue"]) {
    CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewSize, NO, 1.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    MenuViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.backgroundImage = image;
}
```

Then in the next view controller in the viewDidAppear method I am setting that image to a UIImageView.